# Google Chrome Canary Version 54.0.2830.0 not loading Type script source

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, typescript1.8

I am using Google Chrome canary Version 54.0.2830.0. Typescript files are there but those are not loading the code to debug.

[image]

Comment: SO is not the best place to report issues with tools, and particularly with Canary which changes every night. I recommend logging the bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) so it gets fixed.

Comment: I thought there might be some other issue as It does work well on my other laptop.

Comment: That uses same version of Canary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer here so that it may help others.
I was using visual studio Web API project and project settings were not allowing client the access to static files. Due to which chrome was unable to load the Typescript files and map files.
To solve this, i had to add the following line in my web.config file to allow state contents.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```